# Mysql unicode error exception

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a table named link that with japanese language .That is what i used for link text in html.But it just show in browser as ?????.

### My link table [collation-> utf-8 unicode-ci]

```
id     link_name      link_value
0      ホーム          dashboard
1      カレンダー       calendar
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
  $query = "Select * from link";
  $result = mysql_query($query,$db);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  echo '<a href="' . $baseUri .$row['link_value'] . '/index"><img src="../common/img/list.png" ><span><b>' . $row['link_name'] . '</b></span></a>';
  }
  ?>
```

> link url is go perfectly ,but display in browser is not japan language ,just ?????.(question mark) ? How to get

Comment: Run this before your query `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);`

Comment: I agree to @Mihai , if this does not work i think there might be something wrong with your table / database setup. Can you for example export the table and post the create table statement here?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `link` (
  `id` varchar(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `link_name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `link_value` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: I'd start with removing SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_unicode_c even though this is only for the id it is probably the primary key and could cause problems. Change this to utf-8 too

Answer (score 2):

There might be different problems, you should check where the problem occurs: Browser or Backend.

For Browser this will probably fix it:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

For Backend you should try:

```
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

You should also ensure that your table and your column is set to utf8, not only one of these.

Update:

Depending on how you consume your data (e.g. as a service) you should think about adding the following header to your php:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Beware: Dont set the header after you already output something

Comment: Dear sir, i have already that in config.ini  like this...
[database]
adapter  = Mysqli
host     = localhost
username = ***
password =  ***
dbname   = ***
charset  = utf8

Comment: In a first step i suggest you try to expose your results directly. So for example if your file is "readData.php" you do a var_dump or echo of the wanted line. To ensure the results wrap it in html with given charset. Ensure the pure result from the database is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Put that at the top of your page. So the browser knows how to interpret the text.

Comment: i put already ,written in page is display in japan font but only from mysql data is not ok

Comment: See answer from @FrankProvost

Comment: You might need to add your database connection code. Please ensure not to post your password here.

Answer (score 0):

when fetch data in sql.put code in connection query:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

and put at the top of page in head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8")) 
{
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
    exit();
} 
else 
{
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($mysqli));
}
```